# Bootstrap 5 Nested Accordion How to open Top level accordion when opening nested ones through link

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

so i am trying to create a page with bootstrap 5 nested accordions.
The idea is to have a button that opens a nested accordion within another accordion but i cant get that to work.

The button works and it opens the nested accordion but only if the top level one is already opened previously.

Edit* - While EduDev's answer seems to work in opening two levels of accordions a new problem has surfaced.

When you open lets say Accordion #1 and its sub item #1 and then you click on a link that's supposed to open Accordion #1 and sub item #2 the accordion #1 closes all together since it toggles off and on. Any tips on how to navigate this problem with javascript would be really appreciated.

You can check that on this fiddle i made real quick.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t9L45q3/)

My HTML Code Bellow (Updated with EduDev's part:

```
<button data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-collapseOne,#collapseOne"> This should open both Accordion #1 and accordion #1 sub item #1</button>
<button data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo"> This opens accordion #2</button>
<button data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#sub-collapseTwo,#collapseOne"> This should open Accordion #1 and  sub item #2 but only open Accordion #1 if its not already opened if it is it should ignore it and not toggle it.
<div class="container">

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
<div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Accordion #1
        </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">

            <div class="accordion" id="sub-accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="sub-headingOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            Accordion #1 Sub Item #1
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="sub-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="sub-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#collapseOne">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="sub-headingTwo">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sub-collapseTwo">
                            Accordion #1 Sub Item #2
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="sub-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="sub-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#collapseOne">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="sub-headingThree">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sub-collapseTwo">
                            Accordion #1 Sub Item #3
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="sub-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="sub-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#collapseOne">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Accordion #2
        </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">

            <div class="accordion" id="sub2-accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="sub2-headingOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub2-collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                            Accordion #2 Sub Item #1
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="sub2-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="sub2-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sub2-accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="sub2-headingTwo">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub2-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sub2-collapseTwo">
                            Accordion #2 Sub Item #2
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="sub2-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="sub2-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#sub2-accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="sub2-headingThree">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#sub2-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sub2-collapseTwo">
                            Accordion #2 Sub Item #3
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="sub2-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="sub2-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#sub2-accordionExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Have tried messing around with data-bs-target and data-bs-parent to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne,#sub-collapseOne"> This should open both Accordion #1 and accordion #1 sub item #1</button>
```

Not sure whether this is the best solution but it worked in your JSFiddle. Just add the second #anchor to the `href` attribute as well.

Comment: This seem to work but there is one problem. When you have multiple buttons each targeting a different sub accordion inside the main accordion and all of them opening both the main level one and a sublevel and you click from one to the other the main level one just toggles off again and it bugs out since they all open both the main and the sub level ones. My guess is some sort of a javascript workaround has to happend.

Comment: Well, currently all opened sections stay open until you close them. A sub section even stays open, when you close the parent. Question is: What behavior of your sections do you want?

Comment: I would like to be able to swap between sub-sections (children of the main header) with the button click.

Example. I click button 1 that opens Header 1 and sub section 1 then when i click button 2 lets say it should only open sub-section 2 of header 1 but right now it just closes header 1 since both buttons href both the header 1 and a different subsection. Id like to find a way to both open header 1 from both buttons but only if its not already open so it doesn't toggle on and off and then just open the corresponding sub section.